# How to perform multiple search on HTML document using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter

I want to create an application that has two search boxes.
I pass the search keyword to the first box and then to the second. 
Unfortunately, the application does not keep the first search. While entering the second box, the first search is overwritten.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    pre, p{
        background-color:#987563;
    }
    .myInput{
        background-color: #1c1d22;
        color: white;
    article{
         background-color: #acac9a;
         padding: 2%;
         margin: 2%;
    }
</style>   
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });

$("#myInput1").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myDIV *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<section id="myDIV">
<h2> If I type "two" in the first searchbox and than "three" in second, the second searchbox overwrites the first.</h2> 
<p>one two     </p>   
<p>one three     </p>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to keep the result of the first search and do the second search on that first one, please?

Comment: If you want to keep the results of both search boxes, I would simply implement the SAME search function for both boxes -- search for one OR search for the other. By doing the same thing twice, you'll be destroying one or the other. Just a thought -- give both of them the same class, then implement the function to filter #div1 for the contents of input with that class.

Comment: I would suggest using classes instead.  For the first filter, everything that doesn't match your first filter, add 'hideFilterOne' or something that has the display none on it.  And do the same for the second one with 'hideFilterTwo' or something.  Then if filter two would not add the hide class to it, it could still be hidden by the first filter.  They would operate independently, but would also be able to work together.

Comment: Though side note.  You should really be using each() instead of filter() as you are not using that method properly.  `$("#myDIV *").hide().filter(function(){ return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1; }).show()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using classes to hide depending on which search failed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    
    $("#myDIV *").addClass('myInputMismatch').filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
    }).removeClass('myInputMismatch');
  });

  $("#myInput1").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = this.value.toLowerCase();
    
    $("#myDIV *").addClass('myInput1Mismatch').filter(function() {
      return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1;
    }).removeClass('myInput1Mismatch');
  });
});
```

```css
pre,
p {
  background-color: #987563;
}

.myInput {
  background-color: #1c1d22;
  color: white;
}

article {
  background-color: #acac9a;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 2%;
}

.myInputMismatch, .myInput1Mismatch { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<input id="myInput1" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
<section id="myDIV">
  <h2> If I type "two" in the first searchbox and than "three" in second, the second searchbox overwrites the first.</h2>
  <p>one two </p>
  <p>one three </p>
</section>
```

Comment: It works. I will proceed with further testing. Thank you!